# asp .net webform import jquery 404

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

The case:

1.

[image: dir struct]

Directory Structure is like that

  2.

[image: load]

That is how I load the jquery. I have tried using :

```
<%= this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-version.min.js") %>
```

does not work. Using

```
<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-version.min.js") %>
```

Does not work. Using

```
 <%# this.ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-version.min.js") %>
```

Does not work too. Then I try inspect element:

[image: inspect]

Then, I try to load it directly on browser,

[image: directly]

Why my app folder printed twice? at requested URL? That make the code does not work.

I do not understand where is the setting, but I try all ways and still not work?

This is my full directory for web root:
C:\Toha\Kerjaan\E-ProcNominative\e-proc\WebApplication

Comment: Are you wanting to interpolate the version of JQuery?

<%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js") %>

Comment: no, Sir.. The version is that version.. That code is just dummy. I mean why jquery does not loaded.

Comment: its not work because this file `jquery-version.min.js"` is not exist

Comment: The jquery file is included into project, but is it published correctly as well to IIS? Or how do you execute the app? What build action is set on the file? If 'none' then it won't be published. And check the directory structure, is 'js' really a subdirectory of root dir?

Comment: Now I have looked at the printscreen, you have an extra virtual directory 'NominativeList' there. So the scripts are probably here: 'nominativeList/js/jquery-1.1.7.js'.

Comment: correct, dee.. That is the case. I mean, why IIS pointing to wrong virtual directory? Why NominativeList printed twice at requested URL?

Comment: Because in IIS you have the directory structure like this: e.g. 'Default Web Site/NominativeList/nominativeList'? where the second 'nominativeList' is the application.

Comment: Yes, correct. I mean.. Why second nominativeList appears? And I put http://localhost/NominativeList/js/jquery-1.7.1.js  directly to browser does not work? But at another page, (with different folder) the js loaded successfully?

Comment: Should I put something like:   <location path="App_Themes">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location> at web.config?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101564/discussion-between-dee-and-toha).

Comment: Ok.. It is a please..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the jQuery-file name, there is an `"` at the end which causes IIS to search  for a wrong file. IIS searches for `jquery-1.7.1.js%22` which doesn't exist.

```
<script src="here at the end jquery-1.7.1.js"'> ... here removed the `"` after `js`.
```

*(It was a little tricky to find :))*

Comment: Correct answer..
I am just confused why <%= Page.ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-version.min.js") %>
does not work at this page, and work fine at another page. Thank You Sir..

Comment: I guess for this page is the jQuery file in ```js``` dir not in ```Scripts```.